# Centre image horizontally inside li where image wider than li

Tags: html, css

What options (if any) do I have to centre the image within the `li` tag? What I have is an oversized image deliberately placed into a smaller sized li. What I am trying to achieve is the image centred within the li tag ... ie so that the cropped overflow would be shared on both the left and right, not just the right. The code below is a reduced version of what I am working with.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://placehold.it/400x100">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li{
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 250px;
}
img {
  border: 3px solid pink;
}
```

The codepen is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebCEi. Note: I wont be able to use background images.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: To get the image centred within the li tag ... ie so that the cropped overflow would be shared on both the left and right, not just the right - will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 250px;
    position:relative;
    height:106px;
}
img {
    border: 3px solid pink;
    position:absolute;
    left:-75px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Snzdp/)**

You'll notice the left and right border on the image isn't visible because it extends beyond the viewport of the list item.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align`:

```
li {
   overflow:hidden;
   text-align: center; /* <-------  */
   width: 250px;
}
```

If that doesn't work try this:

```
img {
    border: 3px solid pink;
    margin: 0 auto; /* <-------  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://placehold.it/400x100">
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  width: 250px;
}
img {
  border: 3px solid pink;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Ummm, that's because your image is wider than the list item.

Comment: So you want the `li` centered -- not the image. Good luck.

Comment: image centred within li if possible. If it's not possible it would be helpful to see from the specs why not, thanks

Comment: @BhushanFirake yes I know, but that's deliberate too

Comment: Done, sorry I thought it was obvious as it's in the code `overflow:hidden;
  width: 250px;`

Comment: Changed the title too, that probably didn't help.